# How to create an array of values from LI inside a UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a control which allows users to sort the `<li>` in whatever order they want. when the form submits I want to grab the text inside the `<li>`  for each `<li>` put into an array, in the order on the form.

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Protective Services
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Engineering Services and Public Works
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am grabbing the `<li>`'s with:

```
var ar = [];
ar = document.getElementById("sortable").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

I then go through the array:

```
for(i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
    alert(ar[i].text());    //ar[i].anything results in console errors.
}
```

ar[i] displays `[object HTMLLIElement]` for every `<li>` available.
if I try to access the .text/.val/id properties inside the items i get a console error. So I'm assuming this has to do with a parsing/conversion issue?

How do I properly create an array that looks like `protective services,Engineering Services and Public Works` and NOT like `[object HTMLLIElement],[object HTMLLIElement]`? Or how do I access my text information from the `<li>` as a `[object HTMLLIElement]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the jQuery object in order to use `text()`:

```
alert($(ar[i]).text());
```

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/rh6ufn23/1/.

Comment: Can you make the jsfiddle link bigger?

Comment: @CodyStott No, it's streetstyle http://www.stussy.com/us/crown-stripe-tee; everything else would be too big!

Comment: haha yeah just a little bit bigger I can't see it! :P
Thanks for your solution, wasn't aware i had to use jQuery object to use text(). the innerHTML is great but puts all text in upper-case, i would like to keep my formatting the same and not worry about another step, so your solution is the best for me.

Answer (score 3):

For a pure javascript solution use the innertext property

```
alert(ar[i].innerText);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fjursaw/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the properties `ar[i].innerText` or `ar[i].textContent` on DOM nodes. The method `.text()` would be used if you had a jQuery object

```js
var lis = document.getElementById("sortable").getElementsByTagName("li");

var data = [];
for(var i=0; i<lis.length; i++){
   data.push(lis[i].innerText);  
}

var jsonFormated = JSON.stringify(data);
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = jsonFormated;
```

```html
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Protective Services</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Engineering Services and Public Works</li>
</ul>


<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you work with the HTMLElement, which is of vanilla js, not jQuery. Try `.innerHTML` instead of `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution:

```
$('li', '#sortable').each(function(){
    alert($(this).text()); 
});
```

Or to fix your solution in pure JS:

```
var ar = [];
ar = document.getElementById("sortable").getElementsByTagName("li");

for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    alert(ar[i].innerText);
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzc7zLxz/3/).

Comment: There is no need to use replace, using innerText or textContent will give strings that have html tags removed

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
var ar = [];
var listItems = $("#sortable li");
listItems.each(function(li) {
    ar.push($(this).text());
});
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/0uddfms6/